# Firebase reflect changes directly from database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Firebase application I created a fragment that allows users to update their information like namn & email and so far all is going well, however my issue is after the user have updated the information - the changes are not visible untill next relaunch of the application.

How can I reflect the changes directly from the databse without promoting the User to relaunch the app?

I have created a Method called `restart();` that will like the name says says restart the application - But still the changes are not being reflected!

```
/**
     * Update Name Only
     */
    private void updateDisplayNameOnly() {

        showProgress();

        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(), mConfirm.getText().toString());

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(mName.getText().toString())
                                    //.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/862/86285.jpg"))
                                    .build();

                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdate);

                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: User Profile updated");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name is updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            restartApp();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Name was not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        hideProgress();

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        hideProgress();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have entered wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Restart Method

```
public void restartApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a listener onDataChange(), so when you query data from firebase, make sure you implement that, [see doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data). If you want to reflect the change, implement it in this method (like resetting the text fields). There is no need for a restart method.

Comment: The docs is abit confusing for me. Do I simply need to call the `onDataChange()` method in the `if (task.isSuccessful())` ?

Answer (score 0):

Update profile call is asynchronous, and its results are not available immediately, so for some time you'll still observe "obsolete" data.

When you call updateProfile, you get a task as a result. You can subscribe on completion of this task, and if it's completed successfully, then you will be able to get updated data from user instance. E.g.:

```
final FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
Log.i("MyActivity", "before updateProfile: username=" + currentUser.getDisplayName());

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("UPDATED_NAME")
        .build();
final Task<Void> task = currentUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate);
Log.i("MyActivity", "after updateProfile: username=" + currentUser.getDisplayName());

task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Log.i("MyActivity", "onComplete: username=" + currentUser.getDisplayName());
    }
});
```

And here is an output:

> I/MyActivity: before updateProfile: username=old name
>
> I/MyActivity: after updateProfile: username=old name
>
> I/MyActivity: onComplete: username=UPDATED_NAME

Also there is a method user.reload(), which force reload user data from Firebase server. This is useful when your client user cache is obsolete for some reason. It is **also an asynchronous** method, which gives you Task and you need to subscribe on its completion.